# XMLHttpRequest - JS not working on called page

Tags: javascript, ajax

Have called another page through XMLHttpRequest. But the called page can't return JavaScript content.

In below code it's not returning addition of 5+7.

Have gone through various google stuff but nothing seems to be working.

it would be helpful if anyone could crack that....

> request_xml.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Here</p>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
    loadDoc();
};

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "call_page.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> call_page.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>why is js not working?</p>
<script> 
    document.write(5+7);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> Edit:

JavaScript is working when page directly loaded

Also, JS working inside onclick in **call_page.php**

Comment: it's probably escaped, so it isn't parsed as `<script>`. please include a `console.log()` for `this.responseText` so we could see...

Comment: @vsync it's showing nothing on console

Comment: shows nothing? then roll up your sleeves and investigate :)

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript is loaded on page load by the browser. But here you're loading the page with AJAX, which just makes a HTTP request and returns the server's response. Since it's never loaded by browser's rendering engine, the JavaScript doesn't ever load.

You can try injecting the response into a dummy element created with `document.createElement` but most modern browsers won't allow you to execute JavaScript like that. So your best bet is to either find another loading vector or open that other page as a popup or an iframe.

Comment: but inside onclick its working

Comment: Because that's a user initiated event. Browsers act differently based on if the event was user triggered (like onclick) or browser triggered (like onload).